# Atom.io: Emmet and jsx

Tags: atom-editor, emmet, jsx

It seems Emmet is supposed to work with .jsx files too, but I cant get it to work in atom. My divs are not expanding, nothing happens when i press tab. I've tried restarting Atom, disabled all other user packages and it works perfectly with html documents. Should Emmet work with .jsx out of the box or are there configurations needed?

Comment: Have you checked over here? https://github.com/emmetio/emmet-atom/issues/237

Comment: Yup. Tried to revert to the older version but it didn't help.

Comment: @user2768271 Same issue, updating doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of the latest version you can hit cmd + shift + e. I assume for windows or linux it would be ctrl + shift + e (Although I have not verified windows and linux one)

Comment: I want my tags to expand when pressing tab. Building on your answer to achieve this: go to Atom/Open your keymap and paste this: 'atom-text-editor[data-grammar="source js jsx"]:not([mini])': 'tab': 'emmet:expand-abbreviation-with-tab' Now you'll be able to expand with tab. Awesome.

Comment: As of Emmet 2.4.3 Atom 1.6.2 the [data-grammar=...] part does not seem to work. Go to Atom/Keymap and paste this: 'atom-text-editor:not([mini])': 'tab': 'emmet:expand-abbreviation-with-tab' instead. As a side effect this also means that Emmet text expansion will apply to all file -types within Atom.

Comment: @swelet you should write an answer

Answer (score 22):

Open Atom -> Preferences -> Packages -> Emmet

Scroll down a bit and you'll see a note about this particular issue. From there you just need to grab the correct context, which in my case was **source js jsx** and add it to your Keymap configuration.

```
 # Auto expanding for emmet @
 'atom-text-editor[data-grammar="source js jsx"]':
     'tab': 'emmet:expand-abbreviation-with-tab'
```

OR (with a more relaxed selector)

```coffee
# Auto expanding for emmet @
'atom-text-editor[data-grammar*="js"].not:[mini]':
  'tab': 'emmet:expand-abbreviation-with-tab'
```